# Galera Cluster concerns

Tags: mysql, galera

I want to use Galera cluster in our production environment, but  i have some concerns;

1. Each table must have at least one explicit primary key defined.
2. Each table must run under InnoDB or XtraDB storage engine.
3. Chunk up your big transaction in batches. For example, rather than having one transaction insert 100,000 rows, break it up into smaller chunks of e.g., insert 1000 rows per transaction.
4. Your application can tolerate non-sequential auto-increment values.
5. Schema changes are handled differently.
6. Handle hotspots/Galera deadlocks by sending writes to a single node.

I will  like some clarification for all aforementioned points.Also  we have over 600 databases in production, can galera work  in this Environment??

### Thanks

Comment: 600 databases or tables?

Comment: 600 databases!!!

Comment: My [_Galera tips_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/galera) overlap with your list.  You may find some more to worry about.  Some of your 6 (and my N) should not be big issues.  Are they?  If so, focus on them one at a time in separate Questions.

Comment: #4, for example, was already violated in Slaves in ordinary Master-Slave replication.  (id 123 could arrive on the slave _after_ id 124.)

Comment: #3 - replication delays in old M-S with big transactions.

Comment: 600 dbs -- ugly for other reasons, but it should not matter to Galera.

Comment: Thanks alot Rick James.

Comment: 600 dbs -- ugly for other reasons, but it should not matter to Galera, what are the other reasons? and what do you mean by it should not matter to Galera??

Comment: Hundreds of tables or databases is a common discussion under the [mysql] tag.  Galera's implementation does not do anything (that I know of) that would be impacted by the number of databases.  At least not other than would impact MySQL and the OS, independent of Galera.  Each DB is a directory.

Answer (score 0):

That is a **LOT** to handle in one shot. There are two issues, table creation (invloves *Schema*, see point 5) and applications that use those tables. I'll try:

> 1)Each table must have at least one explicit primary key defined.

When you are creating a table, you can't have any table that **DOES NOT** have a primary key. Tables are created with fields and INDEXES. One of those indexes must be declared as PRIMARY KEY.

> 2)Each table must run under InnoDB or XtraDB storage engine.

When tables are created, the must have `ENGINE=InnoDB` or `ENGINE=XtraDB`. Galera does not handle the default MyISAM type tables

> 3)Chunk up your big transaction in batches. For example, rather than
>   having one transaction insert 100,000 rows, break it up into smaller
>   chunks of e.g., insert 1000 rows per transaction.

This is not related to your schema, but your application. Try not to have an application that `INSERT`s a lot of data in one `transaction`. **Note** that this will work, but is risky. This is **NOT** a requirement, but a suggestion.

> 4)Your application can tolerate non-sequential auto-increment values.

With a cluster, you can have multiple servers being updated. If a field is auto-incremented, each cluster member could be trying to increment the same field. Your application should **NEVER EVER** assume that the next ID is related to the previous ID. For auto-increment fields, do not **IMPOSE** a value, let the DB handle it.

> 5)Schema changes are handled differently.

The *Schema* is the description of the tables and indexes and not the transactions that add, delete or retrieve information. You have multiple servers, so a Schema change has to be handled with care, so that all servers do catch up.

> 6)Handle hotspots/Galera deadlocks by sending writes to a single node.

This is both application and DB related. A deadlock is a condition where 2 different parts of an app try to get a value (ValueA), as the DB to lock it so it can be changed, and then try to get another value (ValueB) for the same use. If another part tries to First Lock ValueB , then ValueA, we have a deadlock, Because each app has locked the *next* value of the other app. To avoid this, it's best tp write to only one server in the cluster and use the other servers for reading. Do note that you can still have deadlocks in your applications. But you can avoid Galera creating the situation.

Comment: Thanks alot  Jacques Amar, with respect with point above,wsrep_certify_nonPK=ON - When this variable is enabled, primary keys will be generated automatically for the rows that the rows don't have them.Also, what recommendations do you have for me??

Comment: Thanks alot Jacques Amar, with respect  to  point one(1) above,wsrep_certify_nonPK=ON - When this variable is enabled, primary keys will be generated automatically for the rows that the rows don't have them.Also, what recommendations do you have for me??

Comment: Ugh. Nothing **generic** can be said. It depends on your schemas and applications. In general, the **second** server you add to the cluster (your first one will be your current DB) will work or not. Move your current DB to Galera cluster and see if MySQL starts. Then go on to the second one. It will start and try to replicate the existing data. It will take as long as it needs to do this. SO for 600 DBs .. be patient! The good part is your 3rd and more will be easy!


My experience was that the `sync` technique chosen is the key. I tried rsync and it was a BITCH

Comment: Thanks, but what about the  PK point.with the variable (wsrep_certify_nonPK=ON ) enabled, primary keys will be generated automatically for the rows that the rows don't have them???

Comment: They strongly recommend against relying on it.

http://galeracluster.com/documentation-webpages/mysqlwsrepoptions.html#wsrep-certify-nonpk

Comment: wsrep_certify_nonpk -- I hope that is talking about adding a PK to a _table_, not just to _rows_.

Comment: Rick James, what do you mean by "That is a LOT to handle in one shot"..Dare you talking about the initial loading of the databases or about Galera handling more than 600DBs.

Comment: Rick James, what do you mean by "That is a LOT to handle in one shot"..are you talking about the initial loading of the databases or about Galera handling more than 600DBs

Comment: Jacques said "a lot to..."; I took it to mean that 6 unrelated questions in one Question is a lot.